# Which property should I use in Google SearchConsole

Tags: seo, google-search-console

From my point of view is redundant to add all versions of a website URL like:

```
example.com
www.example.com
http://www.example.com
http://example.com
https://www.example.com
https://example.com
```

My website is going to be exclusively accessible at `https://www.example.com` and all redirects and other adjustments will be towards this.

It makes completely no sense for me to monitor all those property versions.

Comment: You answered your own question: if you aren't going to monitor all of the variants, just register the one that you would use.

Answer (score 3):

Registering the non-canonical properties allow you to check/diagnose configuration errors. For example, if a canonical redirect should fail (or be incorrectly implemented) for whatever reason or SSL cert renewal failures and/or pages aren't being indexed on the canonical property, you have no way of knowing (without doing a less reliable `site:` search) whether those pages have been incorrectly indexed on a non-canonical property by mistake.

> ```
> example.com
> www.example.com
> http://www.example.com
> http://example.com
> https://www.example.com
> https://example.com
> ```

That's 4 properties (not 6), the first two are the same as the second two.

Note that you can also add a [domain property](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en) which aggregates all variations (all subdomains, all protocols) under a single property. You can then "add a [page filter](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7576553#filteringdata) in the Performance report to see data for specific protocols or subdomains".

Comment: The domain property route is the one I would suggest.

Comment: The domain property is missing some features compared to the prefix property.  It cannot be connected to Google Analytics for example.    For a site running on one host name (no additional domain names or subdomains), I recommend the prefix property.